# How to add route for Hexo?

Tags: hexo

In the theme _config.yml has two default route: `/` and `/archieves`. Is there possible to add a route like `/about`?

I tried to add `/about` in _config.yml, but `Cannot GET /about/` shows.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to create a new page by runnning `hexo new page "about"`. A folder will be created in `source/`. In this folder, there is a file named `index.md`. In this file, you can write the content of this page `/about` in markdown.

This page will be displayed as a <del>post</del> `page` layout, if you want an other layout and style, define in front-matter, the layout with `layout: YOUR_LAYOUT`. Of course, you have to create this layout in the `layout` folder of your theme folder. The layout name will be the name of the file.

Answer (score 14):

If you need a page `about` :

1. run `hexo new page "about"`
2. You will find an `about` folder in the `source` folder. You can edit the `index.md` file in the `about` folder.
3. add code `About: /about` in the `menu` section of `_config.yml` file in your theme folder. Preview your site :)

Answer (score 2):

If you need a page `about`,you can run `hexo new page 'about'`,and then add `/about` in `_config.yml`

Answer (score 2):

Three years passed, but maybe someone will find this useful.

If you want to actually add a route (without creating a page directory and/or files) you can use generator. Add this to a `.js` file inside your theme's `scripts` folder:

```
hexo.extend.generator.register("all-posts", function(locals) {
  return {
    path: "all-posts/index.html",
    data: locals,
    layout: ["all-posts", "index"]
  };
});
```

In this example, the page with layout 'all-posts' will be at `/all-posts` url.

This, of course, could be done by creating a folder with `index.md` file in it, with `layout: all-posts` in its front-matter